# Converting json to soap+xml to send to endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I converted this json file to XML
`{ "firstNumber": 25, "secondNumber": 23 }`

but it converts it to this instead;
`<Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <a>25</a> <b>23</b> </Add>`

Now, without headers for soap and the envelop, the endpoint does not recognize this so i use an enrich mediator to make it the right format.

the issue i have is that when i use the enrich mediator, it replaces the entire soap body including the variables.

is there a way i can change only the envelop of the xml message

this is my endpoint
ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/Handouts/cse775/code/calcWebService/Calc.asmx
the documentation is there too

This is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZJL9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o5S5.png)`

Comment: Do not add images of the source code. Add the source code with proper formatting to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your enrich mediator is doing is replacing the Entire message with the Inline payload you have given. Inorder to resolve the issue, remove your `Enrich Mediator` and add the following property before sending the request out.

```xml
<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2"/>
```